# State of eGPUs for laptops in late 2019

Tags: graphics-cards, usb, pcie

I want to upgrade my laptop to have an external GPU. What's the state of things in late 2019?

I would prefer not to remove my WiFi card.

Does such a thing exist for USB-C as well? My laptop has a USB-C port without support for Thunderbolt 3 and with reduced Bandwidth of around 5 Gbit/s. It also has a free USB 3.0 port. What's the optimal solution for me?

P.S Does [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32861221054.html) fit me?

Related answer: https://superuser.com/a/1097008/1023037

Comment: @K7AAY I looked up the hardware manual of my laptop and found out that my WiFi card uses a M.2 slot. There's no extra information I can gain from publishing my model number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the state of things in late 2019?

There are currently two ways to install an external GPU to a laptop.

- By using an internal PCIe connection and a cable leading to a PCIe GPU enclosure.
  This is often done through the port for the WiFi card. If your laptop is new enough it might have a spare M.2 port that supports PCIe for an SSD or a cellular modem.
- By using a Thunderbolt 3 port and a cable leading to a PCIe GPU enclosure.

In the near future USB 4.0 will incorporate the Thunderbolt 3 protocol. This will likely cause the current Thunderbolt 3 enclosures to be supported by a large number of laptops with USB 4.0 support.

> Does such a thing exist for USB-C as well?

No and yes.

"USB-C" is a specification supporting USB 3.x. There is no support for exposing PCI express through USB-C.

Thunderbolt 3 is an entirely separate specification that *supports* USB 3.x and PCI express. It also uses the USB-C connector but the port is considered a "Thunderbolt" port, not "USB". Thunderbolt devices usually require a superior quality cable too.

> What's the optimal solution for me?

It looks like the adapter you linked *might* work with the WiFi slot, but it will be significantly slower than a Thunderbolt 3 connection, and may bottleneck the GPU. If your laptop is new enough you might need to use an M.2 version of a kit like that, since many WiFi cards come in an M.2 slot now.

Comment: My laptop is new, but apparently doesn't contain a M.2 slot..

Comment: @SirMuffington, Still take notice of the WiFi card's slot. It could either be mini PCIe or M.2 these days.